# Error: Uncaught Assertion Failed!:

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting below error while executing my lightning component.

> Uncaught Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key '{c.datechange}'. No value provider was found for '{c'. : false

Apex Class:

```
public class TMNLBookAppointmentController {

    @AuraEnabled public static map<String,boolean> getSlotMap(integer years,integer months,integer days) {
        list<String> listofSlots = new list<String>();
        set<string> bookedSlots= new set<string>();
        Date startdates = Date.newInstance(integer.valueof(years),integer.valueof(months)
                                           ,integer.valueof(days));
        for(event e:[select startdatetime,DurationInMinutes   from event where ownerId=:userinfo.getUserId() 
                     and ActivityDate=:startdates] ) {
                   Integer Min= e.startdatetime.minute();
                   integer hr= e.startdatetime.hour();
                   for(integer i=0; i<e.DurationInMinutes; i+=30) {
                       BookedSlots.add(string.valueof(hr)+':'+string.valueof(Min));
                       if(min==30){
                           min=0;
                           hr+=1;
                       } else {
                           min+=30;
                       }   

                   }   

        }

        Map<String,boolean> Mymap = new Map<String,boolean>();
         Mymap.put('key17',BookedSlots.contains('8:0'));
         Mymap.put('key18',BookedSlots.contains('8:30'));
         Mymap.put('key1',BookedSlots.contains('9:0'));
         Mymap.put('key2',BookedSlots.contains('9:30'));
         Mymap.put('key3',BookedSlots.contains('10:0'));
         Mymap.put('key4',BookedSlots.contains('10:30'));
         Mymap.put('key5',BookedSlots.contains('11:0'));
         Mymap.put('key6',BookedSlots.contains('11:30'));
         Mymap.put('key7',BookedSlots.contains('12:0'));
         Mymap.put('key8',BookedSlots.contains('12:30'));
         Mymap.put('key9',BookedSlots.contains('13:0'));
         Mymap.put('key10',BookedSlots.contains('13:30'));
         Mymap.put('key11',BookedSlots.contains('14:0'));
         Mymap.put('key12',BookedSlots.contains('14:30'));
         Mymap.put('key13',BookedSlots.contains('15:0'));
         Mymap.put('key14',BookedSlots.contains('15:30'));
         Mymap.put('key15',BookedSlots.contains('16:0'));
         Mymap.put('key16',BookedSlots.contains('16:30'));
         Mymap.put('key19',BookedSlots.contains('17:0'));
         Mymap.put('key20',BookedSlots.contains('17:30'));
        return MyMap;
    }


    @AuraEnabled public static Void createEvent(String Sub,String startdate,boolean email,Id opptyId,String Description, String slot) {
        //1.- Variable initialisation
        Event newEvent= new Event();
        system.debug(startdate+'*******************');
        //2.- Accomplish query
        try {
          // Fetch Primary Contact email  
          //String contactEmail=[select Email from Contact where id In (select contactid from opportunityContactRole where OpportunityId=:opptyId and IsPrimary=true)].email;
          Integer d = Date.valueOf(startdate).day();
          Integer mo = Date.valueOf(startdate).month();
          Integer yr = Date.valueOf(startdate).year();
          list<string> Slotsplit= slot.split(':');
          integer hr=integer.valueof(Slotsplit[0]);
          integer mn=integer.valueof(Slotsplit[1]); 
          DateTime DT = DateTime.newInstance(yr, mo, d, hr, mn, 00);
          // Create event.
          newEvent.Subject=Sub;
          newEvent.StartDateTime=dt;
          newEvent.EndDateTime=(newEvent.StartDateTime).addminutes(30);  
          if(opptyId.getsobjectType().getDescribe().getname()=='Lead' || 
             opptyId.getsobjectType().getDescribe().getname()=='Contact') {
                newEvent.WhoId=opptyId; 
             } else {
                newEvent.WhatId=opptyId;     
             }

          //newEvent.whoId=[select contactid from opportunityContactRole where OpportunityId=:opptyId and IsPrimary=true].contactid; 
          //newEvent.Send_Email_to_Customer__c=email; 
          //newEvent.Contact_Email__c= contactEmail;
          newEvent.Description= Description;   
          newEvent.ownerId=UserInfo.getUserId();
          insert newEvent;  
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@TMNLBookAppointmentController.getOppty ERROR:' + e.getMessage());
            //TODO: DML for Error logging
        } 
        //3.- method return results
        //return null;
    }
}
```

===============================================================

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="TMNLBookAppointmentController" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" 
                access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="SlotMap" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="today" type="DateTime" />
    <aura:attribute name="event" type="Event" default="{'sobjectType': 'Event'}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.today}" action="{!c.datechange}"/>
    <div  class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">

        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-3 slds-medium-size--2-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="Subject" value="Callback Appointment" label="Subject" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-3 slds-medium-size--2-of-6 slds-large-size--3-of-12">
            <ui:inputDate aura:id="Startdate" label="Appointment Date" class="field" value="{!v.today}" displayDatePicker="true" required="true" change="{c.datechange}"/>   
        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-3 slds-medium-size--2-of-6 slds-large-size--3-of-12">
            <ui:inputSelect label="Time" class="dynamic" aura:id="TimeSelect"/>   
        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="Description" value="{!v.event.Description}" label="Description"/>
        </div>
        <!--   Removed after discussing with Martijn and Made it generic for lead as well
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal-small slds-size-1-of-1">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" label="Send Email?"/>
        </div>  -->

    </div>
    <div class="slds-p-horizontalsmall sldssize1of1">
         .
    </div>
    <div  class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
        <br/>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key17}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">08:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="08:00" id="8:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">08:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key18}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">08:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="08:30" id="8:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">08:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key1}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">09:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="09:00" id="9:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">09:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key2}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">09:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="09:30" id="9:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">09:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key3}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">10:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="10:00" id="10:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">10:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key4}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">10:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="10:30" id="10:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">10:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key5}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">11:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="11:00" id="11:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">11:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key6}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">11:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="11:30" id="11:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">11:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key7}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">12:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="12:00" id="12:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">12:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key8}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">12:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="12:30" id="12:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">12:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key9}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">13:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="13:00" id="13:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">13:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key10}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">13:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="13:30" id="13:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">13:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key11}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">14:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="14:00" id="14:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">14:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key12}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">14:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="14:30" id="14:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">14:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key13}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">15:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="15:00" id="15:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">15:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key14}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">15:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="15:30" id="15:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">15:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key15}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">16:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="16:00" id="16:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">16:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key16}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">16:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="16:30" id="16:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">16:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
        <!-- To remove -->

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key19}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">17:00</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="17:00" id="17:0" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">17:00</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.SlotMap.key20}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" disabled="true">17:30</button></div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-8"><button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" label="17:30" id="17:30" onclick="{!c.SetTime}">17:30</button></div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
        <!-- End -->
    </div>
    <div class="slds-p-horizontalsmall sldssize1of1">
         .
    </div>    
    <div class="slds-p-horizontalsmall sldssize1of1">
            <ui:button class="btn slds-button--brand slds-align--center" label="Submit" press="{!c.setOutput}"/>
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

==========================================================

Lightning Controller:

```
({  
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
       var opts = [
           { class: "optionClass", label: "08:00", value: "8:0"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "08:30", value: "8:30"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "09:00", value: "9:0"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "09:30", value: "9:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "10:00", value: "10:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "10:30", value: "10:30"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "11:00", value: "11:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "11:30", value: "11:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "12:00", value: "12:0"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "12:30", value: "12:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "13:00", value: "13:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "13:30", value: "13:30"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "14:00", value: "14:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "14:30", value: "14:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "15:00", value: "15:0"},
           { class: "optionClass", label: "15:30", value: "15:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "16:00", value: "16:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "16:30", value: "16:30" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "17:00", value: "17:0" },
           { class: "optionClass", label: "17:30", value: "17:30" }
        ];
      component.find("TimeSelect").set("v.options", opts);      
       var today = new Date();
       component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate());
       var action = component.get('c.getSlotMap');
        action.setParams({
           "years":today.getFullYear(),
            "months":today.getMonth()+1,
            "days":today.getDate(),
        });
       action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set('v.SlotMap',response.getReturnValue());

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 

     },



    datechange: function(component, event, helper) {   
     var AppointmentStart = component.find("Startdate").get("v.value");
      var today = AppointmentStart.split("-");
       var action = component.get('c.getSlotMap');
        action.setParams({
           "years":today[0],
            "months":today[1],
            "days":today[2],
        });
       action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set('v.SlotMap',response.getReturnValue());

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
     },



    SetTime: function(component, event, helper) {      
        var timeslot=event.target.id;
        component.find("TimeSelect").set("v.value",timeslot);
     },



    setOutput : function(component, event, helper) {
      //1.- get values from UI
      var opptyId=component.get("v.recordId");       
      var ValidateFields=true; 
      //var emailCheck=component.find("checkbox").get("v.value"); 
      var descrip= component.find("Description").get("v.value");
      var slot= component.find("TimeSelect").get("v.value"); 
      // Checking for field validation Subject
      var inputCmp1 = component.find("Subject");
      var Sub = inputCmp1.get("v.value");
      if (!Sub) {
        inputCmp1.set("v.errors", [{message:"Enter the Subject of Appointment"}]);
        ValidateFields=false;  
      } else {
        //clear error
        inputCmp1.set("v.errors", null);
      }

      // Checking field validation for Date
      var inputCmp2 = component.find("Startdate");
      var AppointmentStart = inputCmp2.get("v.value");
      if (!AppointmentStart) {
        inputCmp2.set("v.errors", [{message:"Enter the Appointment DateTime"}]);
        ValidateFields=false;  
      } else {
        //clear error
        inputCmp2.set("v.errors", null);
      }

       if(ValidateFields){  
        var eventcreation= component.get("c.createEvent"); 
        //2.- Set Parameters
        eventcreation.setParams({
           "Sub":Sub,
           "startdate":AppointmentStart,
           "email": 'True',
           "opptyId": opptyId,
            "Description":descrip,
            "slot":slot,
        });

       //3.- Callback for post processing
        eventcreation.setCallback(this, function(response) {  console.log('SAVED.'); window.location.reload(); } );
        //4.- Action request
        $A.enqueueAction(eventcreation);
       }
    },

})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{!c.datechange}` ? (exclamation mark missing)

Comment: Ohh.. My bad ... Silly mistake.. Thanks !! It worked :)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer Can you post that as an answer? Granted it was a typo but the error message isn't that clear and others could search for it in the future!